# Are there any intuitive ways to debug custom WIC codecs?

Tags: codec, decoder, wic

I have been attempting to set up a custom WIC codec using various different templates from GitHub. After successfully compiling and registering the new codecs as well as updating the registries, I have found that it is still impossible to open any custom images. I attempted to have the DLL output a file every time a function is called, yet I am not receiving any feedback. Is there any intuitive way to debug a WIC codec to see why function calls are not being made, or possibly what portions need editing?

For reference, the WIC codec starting point I am using in this case is the .lisa file encoder/decoder found at *https://github.com/ReneSlijkhuis/example-wic-codec*

Comment: You should be able to debug it. Attach to Explorer.exe or DllHost.exe or any other .exe that uses WIC. If you see nothing at all, it's probably a registration issue. BTW I've tested the sample with its installer and it works fine for me.

Comment: You are most likely correct about the registration issue. I went through installation on a separate machine with no issues, so I have a bit more testing to do to figure out what the issue is with the first installation. Out of curiosity though, is there any good reference on the order functions are normally called for the decoder? If I could get an idea of the code flow, it would help me immensely with documentation.

Comment: COM registration issue are often 32 vs 64 bit issues. I only know official WIC documentation from Microsoft. AFAIK, there's nothing else unfortunately (no book, etc.)